# Create one column based on another dataframe col

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one dataframe which has the following structure, called "df"

```
Date        Pxlast    RSI
1-1-2006    403.4     103.4
2-1-2006    403.2     48.2
3-1-2006    394.2     492.2
    .
    . 
    .
```

I have to create a new dataframe that the first two columns will be the same, here is the code for that.

```
senialesActivo = as.data.frame(df[,1:2])
names(senialesActivo)[1:2] = names(df)[1:2]
```

Then I have to create a third column on senialesActivo, that depending if in "df" column "RSI" is more than 50 I have to assign 1 or 0.

Here is an output example for "senialesActivo" dataframe:

```
  Date     Pxlast   Signal_RSI
1-1-2006    403.4        1
2-1-2006    403.2        0 
3-1-2006    394.2        1
```

As you can see in "df" dataframe for date 1-1-2006 we have a RSI value of 103.4, so for my new senialesActivo Dataframe I have to create a new col where to that date I have to assing 1, if the value is greather than 50 or 0 if it's less than that value.

Here is an idea of what I have to do, but this doesn't work.

```
apply(df[,3],2, ifelse(df[,3] < umbral_RSI, senialesActivo[3] == 0 , senialesActivo[3] == 1  ))
```

Comment: Try `with(df,   as.integer( RSI > 50))`

Comment: Do you have a unique `Pxlast` value for each `Date`?

Comment: Yes , you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
senialesActivo$Signal_RSI <- ifelse(df$RSI > 50, 1, 0)
senialesActivo
      Date Pxlast Signal_RSI
1 1-1-2006  403.4          1
2 2-1-2006  403.2          0
3 3-1-2006  394.2          1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without any `ifelse`

```
senialesActivo$Signal_RSI <- with(senialesActivo, as.integer( RSI > 50))
```